Rewriting the Euclidean on-shell action of Schwarzschild-AdS
The Schwarzschild-AdS solution is given by
\begin{align}
 \label{eq: Schwarzschild-AdS metric}
 ds^2=-f(r)dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{f(r)}+r^2d\Omega^2\,,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
 f(r)=1-\frac{2MG}{r}-\frac{\Lambda r^2}{3}\,.
\end{align}
This metric has an event horizon when $f\left(r_h\right)=0$, which is a cubic polynomial equation for $r_h$,
\begin{align}
 r_h-2MG-\frac{\Lambda r_h^3}{3}=0\,.
\end{align}
After considering the Gibbons-Hawking-York contribution, the Euclidean on-shell action of General Relativity reads
\begin{align}
 I_\text{E}\approx-i\beta\left(\frac{M}{2}+\frac{\Lambda r_h^3}{6G}\right)\,,
\end{align}
where $\approx$ stands for a relation that holds on-shell, and
\begin{align}
 \beta=\frac{4\pi}{f'(r_h)}=\frac{4\pi}{2MG/r_h^2-2\Lambda r_h^2/3}\,,
\end{align}
is the (inverse of) Hawking's temperature. We identify $I_\text{E}$ as the logarithm of the partition function in the saddle-point approximation,
\begin{align}
 \ln Z\equiv iI_\text{E}=\beta\left(\frac{M}{2}+\frac{\Lambda r_h^3}{6G}\right)\,.
\end{align}
I want to obtain the internal energy and the entropy, given by relations
\begin{align}
U=\frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial\beta}\,,\quad S=\left(\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}-1\right)\ln Z\,,
\end{align}
respectively. Although I'm sure that the obtained logarithm of the partition function is the right one, I am unable to obtain the internal energy and the entropy (or to rewrite the logarithm of the partition function as the free energy $F=M-\frac{S}{\beta}$, with $S=A/(4G)$, where $A=4\pi r_h^2$).
Perhaps a trick that may be useful is to rewrite the integration constant associated to the mass $M$ in terms of $\Lambda$ and $r_h$, given by relation $f(r_h)=0$,
\begin{align}
M=-\frac{r_h\left(-3+\Lambda r_h^2\right)}{6G}\,,
\end{align}
however, I obtain nothing.

Consider to provide references for context.

To be honest, I don't know references for this concrete calculation. However, I'll put some references regarding e.g., the general formalism, since the article of Gibbons and Hawking is details the Schwarzschild case.

I think you are almost there. First of all,
\begin{align}
\beta = \frac{4\pi}{2MG/r_h^2 - 2\Lambda r_h/3}
\end{align}
is easy to verify and it differs from what you wrote because of a trivial typo. Next you can use the fact that the internal energy of a black hole is nothing but the mass. So
\begin{align}
F = M - \frac{S}{\beta} = U - \frac{S}{\beta} = \frac{1}{\beta} \ln Z = \frac{M}{2} + \frac{\Lambda r_h^3}{6G}.
\end{align}
It is now a pleasure to verify that
\begin{align}
S = \beta(M - F) = \frac{\pi r_h^2}{G} = \frac{A}{4G}.
\end{align}
Update
Note that since entropy is really $\beta(U - F)$, it is the last step where we really needed to know that $U = M$. To show this, it is indeed useful to use your $f(r_h) = 0$ solution. Plugging this into $\beta$ and $\ln Z$ gives
\begin{align}
\beta = -\frac{4\pi r_h}{\Lambda r_h^2 - 1}, \quad \ln Z = -\frac{\pi r_h^2}{3G} \frac{\Lambda r_h^2 + 3}{\Lambda r_h^2 - 1}.
\end{align}
This is enough information to compute
\begin{align}
U = \frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial \beta} = \frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial r_h} / \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial r_h}
\end{align}
and get back your expression for $M$.

"Next you can use the fact that the internal energy of a black hole is nothing but the mass", this is one of the things I'm trying to show. How can I obtain the mass as $U=\frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial \beta}$ from the expression I got?

Ah, I'll add a derivation.

Thanks in advance!

I already added it.

It worked. Thank you!
